# How to select option in select list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a form that has select element

```
<select name="adddisplaypage[]" id="adddisplaypage" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="all" label="all">all</option>
    <option value="index" label="index">index</option>
    <option value="tour" label="tour">tour</option>
    <option value="aboutus" label="about us">about us</option>
    <option value="contactus" label="contact us">contact us</option>
    <option value="destination" label="destination">destination</option>
    <option value="reservation" label="reservation">reservation</option>
</select>
```

can anyone help me to select this option (multiple select) on click i.e the option gets selected when clicked, and deselected if selected on click.

Comment: Isn't this the exact behaviour of a normal browser?

Comment: i don't know!! I have to click Ctr+click to select multiple option

Comment: use toggle on click of options

Comment: Well yes, that's absolutely normal browser behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I may have misunderstood your question. Something like the following should work, though I'm not sure about browser support:

```
$('#adddisplaypage option').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);

  if(self.attr('selected') == '') {
    self.attr('selected', 'selected');
  } else {
    self.attr('selected', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: your idea works but code is not working +1 for idea. I am not being to change the attribute "selected" by your code, i tried my own but still not working.

Comment: P.S what i did was manually set selected attribute from firebug

Answer (score 2):

In your `click()` handler, you could write something like:

```
$("#adddisplaypage").val("index");
```

That should select "index", for example.

Comment: it selects only one index. i want multiple index to be selected.

Comment: I think @Brian's answer below is what you might need!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to the `.val()` method. For instance:

```
$('#adddisplaypage').val(['index', 'tour']);
```